# Stripe checkout not working in angular 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, stripe-payments, angular-routing

I am using stripe payment to process payments. I followed this [GITHUB](https://github.com/laurihy/angular-payments) project and this [blog](https://www.airpair.com/javascript/integrating-stripe-into-angular-app).

My project has nested views and uses routers as well.

My project structure looks like

```
src
  app
    views
    controllers
    directives
    index.html
    app.js
```

The app.js is where angular module is loaded manually and has the routers.

***app.js***

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'formData']);
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) { 
    // routers
}
```

The index.html is where the angular and stripe scripts are included

***index.html***

```
<head lang="en">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
    <Script src="resources/angular.min.js"></Script>
    <Script src="resources/angular-ui-router.min.js"></Script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="directives/formData/formData.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
        src="resources/angular-payments.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        Stripe.setPublishableKey('key')
    </script>
</head>
<div>
    <div ui-view>   
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the formData directive is where I am trying to include the strip payment

***formData.js***

```
    var formData = angular.module('formData',['angularPayments']);
formData.directive('formData',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {},
        replace: true,
        link: function($scope, element, attributes){

        },
        controller: function($scope,$attrs,$http, $state){
            //This is the callback for strip from the links above as followed
            $scope.stripeCallback = function (code, result) {
                console.log("inside cc callbakc");
                if (result.error) {
                    console.log("credit card error");
                    window.alert('it failed! error: ' + result.error.message);
                } else {
                    console.log(result);
                    console.log("credit card succes "+result.id);
                    window.alert('success! token: ' + result.id);
                }
            };

        },
        templateUrl: 'directives/formData/formData.tpl.html'
    }
});
```

formData.tpl.html has another ui router

***formData.tpl.html***

```
<form id="signup-form" ng-submit="processForm()">
    <!-- our nested state views will be injected here -->
    <div  ui-view></div
</form>
```

and one of the ui router html page is the payment page with this code

```
<form stripe-form="stripeCallback" name="checkoutForm">>
    <input ng-model="number" placeholder="Card Number" 
             payments-format="card" payments-validate="card" name="card" />
    <input ng-model="expiry" placeholder="Expiration" 
             payments-format="expiry" payments-validate="expiry"                
             name="expiry" />
    <input ng-model="cvc" placeholder="CVC" payments-format="cvc" payments-validate="cvc" name="cvc" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I get the validations working but nothing prints in the console when I hit submit. I guess the js is not being fired. Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

This will render as nested forms, which is invalid html. Most browsers are silently 'forgiving' of this by treating the inner form as a non-form element. 
If you move the checkoutForm out from the signup-form, this should put you on the right track.

Comment: Yes if I have this outside of the signup form it works. But I really need this inside there